# Apending information based on Text Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an input box that will only be excepted a dollar value.  Based upon the dollar value I would like a div to swap out information.  So basically I need to associate a value range to some content, based upon the input value and swap the content on blur.  Below is code that doesn't work but sort of gives you an idea on what I am trying to accomplish.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
<input type="text" />

$(function(){

 var low = 5
  mid = 10
  high = 15
  val = $('input').val()

if ( val >= low && val < mid){
val.blur(function() {
    val.append('<div>You cheapo!</div>');
});

}

if ( val >= mid && val < high){
val.blur(function() {
    val.append('<div>You middle class folk!</div>');
});
}

if ( val >= high){
val.blur(function() {
    val.append('<div>Woah baller!</div>');
});

}

});
```

Comment: the only problem you really had was that you were using the input value as a jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to wait until the `blur` event fires, before getting the value of the input `val`. Secondly you only want to react to one blur event and then execute your logic, so set that up first. Once you have the value you can use your logic to set the `text` inside of another div, rather than creating a new one on the fly.

This is what I think you code should look like in order to work:

```
$(function() {
    var low = 5,
        mid = 10,
        high = 15;

    function getText(val) {
        if (val >= low && val < mid)
            return 'You cheapo!'
        else if (val >= mid && val < high)
            return 'You middle class folk!'
        else if (val >= high)
            return 'Woah baller!'
        else
            return 'Out of range'
    }

    $('input').blur(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#target').text(getText(val));
    });
});
```

and here is an example of it in action:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/gKBUr/5/

Comment: I think the nested ternary operators hurt readability much more than they help in this case, especially since it seems Chad isn't that familiar with javascript, or programming in general. I would set the message in a variable using standard `if` statements, then assign the value at the end of the function call.

Comment: @Marcus: +1. With the changes I think it's the best answer. It does exactly what he's asking for and should be fairly easy to dissect/understand.

Comment: Agreed. Of all the solutions on the page, I would use this one. (+1)

Comment: Yep this makes since.  I wouldn't say that I am foreign to javaScript and programming by any means.  But I will admit that I haven't done enough event driven scripting.  Thanks a lot for this though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the `.blur()` event to the value of the textbox. Bind it to the textbox itself.

Something like

```
var obj = $("input");


obj.blur(function(){
    // do your code
});
```

And you can use `.before()` or `.after()` to show the div.

```
obj.after("<div/>");
```

Didn't test.

```
$(function () {
    var low = 5;
    var mid = 10;
    var high = 15;
    var inp = $('input');
    var val = inp.val();

    if (val >= low && val < mid) {
        inp.blur(function () {
            inp.after('<div>You cheapo!</div>');
        });
    }

    if (val >= mid && val < high) {
        inp.blur(function () {
            inp.after('<div>You middle class folk!</div>');
        });
    }

    if (val >= high) {
        inp.blur(function () {
            inp.after('<div>Woah baller!</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure where to start to help you, other than show you how it could be done...

```
$('input').blur( function() {
    var low = 5;
    var mid = 10;
    var high = 15;
    var val = $(this).val();

    if ( val >= low && val < mid){
        $('#div-you-want-it-to-appear-in').html('<div>You middle class folk!</div>');
    }

    if ( val >= mid && val < high){
        $('#div-you-want-it-to-appear-in').html('<div>You middle class folk!</div>');
    }

    if ( val >= high){
        $('#div-you-want-it-to-appear-in').html('<div>You middle class folk!</div>');
    }

});
```

Comment: you are doing the same pit fall as him, u are using the value of the input as a jquery object lol

Comment: where am I using `val` as a jQuery object?